# build error on heroku; trying to make a discord bot

Tags: javascript, github, heroku, discord, discord.js

[image: Heroku error]

I'm trying to have a discord bot on 24/7 using heroku, but I'm having this build error. I've asked multiple people and I haven't gotten a response. If anyone can help, much appreciated!

Comment: There is no discord.js v16 right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out your `package.json`, you are trying to install Discord.js `v16.11.0`. That is not a thing yet, the latest version is [v13.2.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js)